# How to make pdf show current date?

Tags: xetex, datetime, acrotex

Is there a way to make a pdf show the current date (not the date when it was compiled, but when it was opened/printed)? I'm making some sign sheets and it would be great if I could put the date in there instead of requiring people to fill it in manually -- but recompiling the file every time just to get the date in there is absolutely stupid. I've been trying to use JavaScript for this (with AcroTeX), but I wasn't successful; clearly my JS skills have got somewhat rusty since I last used it (12 years ago).

Comment: I already tried tdclock before... and I clearly have to learn to really get rid of _everything_ unnecessary when I'm making an MWE. Of course it works now, making me feel like an idiot. Still, thanks.